# Spring boot micrometer metrics mbean suffixed with type=timers

Tags: java, spring-boot, mbeans, spring-micrometer

I have spring boot app with some classes annotated as timed from micrometer. the layout is that it uses telegraph to send metrics to graphite. Did not go with custom metrics or actual declaration of Timers anywhere in the code, just simple "timed" annotations where applicable.This has worked for me so far for many apps.

My problem is in the new app some httpclient requests are suffixed with ",type=timers" and some or not and they even show up differently in jconsole Mbean view. I wish to understand the proper way of doing this. Any help is appreciated.

Just noticed that the bad ones are enclosed in double quotes for some reason.(metrics:name="http*")

Some are MBean -> metrics -> timers -> objectName =

```
metrics:name=httpClientRequests.method.GET.status.404.uri./some/rest/api/{pathParam},type=timers
```

Some are MBean -> metrics = (this is special it just says ",type" but no more)

```
metrics:name="httpClientRequests.method.GET.status.200.uri./some/rest/api/{pathParam}?q=basicinfo&fields=someParam,someMore,type"
```

Some are MBean -> metrics = (this doesnt have any suffix at all.)

```
metrics:name="httpClientRequests.method.GET.status.200.uri./some/rest/api/\?q={query}"
```

[image: below is the screen shot]